# How to specify specific request mapping url

Tags: spring

sorry i am new to spring boot and trying to learn, i have this code that when i run it will open a json request of my catalog item if i enter any url that is localhost/catalog/(any userid). But i want to narrow it to 1 specific userid how can i do that? for example i dont want any url to work except localhost/catalog/friends or any other item from the list i mention.

Code:

```
package com.poc.moviecatalog.controller;

import com.poc.moviecatalog.models.CatalogItem;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class MovieController {

    @RequestMapping("/{userId}")
    public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
       return Collections.singletonList(
               new CatalogItem("friends", "test", 9)
       );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question correctly, you don't want to provide a mapping for any user id, but want one specific endpoint `/catalog/friends`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class FriendsController {

    @GetMapping("/friends")
    public List<Friends> getFriends() {
      ....
    }
}
```

then the url would be: `http:<HOST>:<PORT>/catalog/friends`

Comment: Thank you for replying Mark, i see your point but what if i use an arrays.aslist() and i have multiple items from the list and i want to choose which one i want to put in the url. for example http:localhost/catalog/friends or http:localhost/catalog/gameofthrones

Comment: In this case you did everything right, by using path variable. Then in controller you can verify whether there is an entry in the list of [gameofthrones, friends] and if its an invalid path return 404 HTTP status for example.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Can you please show me how to write the code for it.